# Склонение женских имён, составленных из слов мужского рода

Tags: грамматика, склонение, ономастика, род

Разбираю один текст, и в нём есть много собственных имён для кошек и котов (именно имён, а не фамилий), составленных из обычных слов- существительных и прилагательных (на манер племенных имён коренных народов). Причём, слова используются в обоих родах, и для обоих полов. Особую проблему я вижу в склонениях женских имён из слов мужского рода. Они в тексте иногда склоняются по своему роду, а иногда пишутся в именительном падеже. Как по мне, правильный лишь какой-то один вариант. При этом, мужские имена почти всегда склоняются по своему роду. Далее несколько предложений для примера.

*Справочно, пол носителей имён.*
Тихий Дождь, Звонкий Ручеек, Черепаший Хвостик, Росный Лист, Бегущая Вода - кошки, женский пол.
Лунная Тень, Кривой Сук, Крик Галки, Зубчатый Пик - коты, мужской пол.

**Собственно примеры. *В скобках курсивом- мои варианты или комментарии*. Вне скобок- текст из издания:**

  Глаза Звонкий Ручеек
  *(Звонкого Ручейка)*
  просияли, однако она решительно покачала головой.

  Они со Звонким Ручейком
  *(это ж.р.)*
  уселись перед заячьей тушкой и принялись за еду.

  Отчаянные вопли Звонкий Ручеек
  *(Звонкого Ручейка)*
  стихали вдали.

  «Делайте что хотите, только сначала разбудите Лунную Тень
  *(это мужское имя, представленное словами ж.р.)*
  », - донесся до него голос Черепашьего Хвостика.

  Овраг показался Серому Крылу притихшим и опустевшим.

  - До свидания, - промурлыкал он, потершись лбом о плечо Тихого Дождя
  *(это кошка, т.е. ж.р.)*
  .

  - Идем, Зубчатый Пик, - поманила его Снежная Зайчиха, незаметно кивая Тихий Дождь
  *(Тихому Дождю)*
  .

  - Это будет чудесное приключение! - зеленые глаза Черепаший Хвостик
  *(Черепашьего Хвостика)*
  радостно просияли.

  Серое Крыло проводил взглядом Кривого Сука
  *(м.р.)*
  и Росный Лист
  *(ж.р. Росного Листа)*
  , уходивших на охоту.

  Не успел он договорить, как Серое Крыло увидел Бегущую Воду и Крик Галки
  *(Крика Галки)*
  , которые карабкались вверх по склону, неся в зубах зайца.

  …, а Чистое Небо подталкивает Зубчатый Пик
  *(Зубчатого Пика)*
  на большой, занесенный снегом камень.

Прошу Вашей помощи, хочу разобраться и понять, как верно склоняются подобные имена.

*p.s. Вся книга насыщена подобными различными вариантами, и это детская книга. В сообществе много детей, и я не знаю, как верно им объяснить, какой вариант правильный (да и сам не пойму, т.к. школу окончил в 2004 и более русский язык не изучал).*

Comment: Когда Зубчатый Пик и Дождевой Цветок обсуждают, кто должен поговорить с Чистым Небом, Зубчатый Пик считает, что Дождевой Цветок должна идти, ведь она была подругой Звонкого Ручейка.

Comment: Этот отрвывок случайно не из вашей книги?

Comment: Это отрывок статьи о Звонком Ручейке с вики. К слову, на вики та же путаница - разные участники используют различные варианты при написании статей, и я хотел бы положить этому конец и ввести какой-то единый вариант.

Comment: Я у них спросил, почему они не сколняют, вот их ответ: "В русском переводе имена кошек, состоящие из слов мужского рода, не всегда склоняются. Может даже, никогда не склоняются, это надо проверять. Но в винительном падеже точно, чтобы не выглядело, будто персонаж мужского пола".

Comment: Я за ваш вариант. В русском языке у одушевеленных имен существительных винтельный падеж ( у слов мужского рода) совпадает с родительным. Поэтому правильно склонять: Звонкого ручейка, Черепашьего Хвостика ...и т.д.

Answer (score 2):

Моя рекомендация: **склонять, руководствуясь грамматическим родом таких имен, забыв о половой принадлежности носителя**.

Когда-то давно, помнится, обсуждали это вопрос применительно к именам героев. Майн Рида, Купера, Киплинга. Не могу найти, но смысл понятен. Стоит, однако, упомянуть, что переводчики обычно подбирают подходящий пол объекта или им приходится выкручиваться со смыслом ("Стрекоза и муравей" - у Лафонтена это две кумушки, "На севере кедр одинокий" в оригинале Гейне - сосна и пальма - любовь вполне гетеросексуальна).  А вот как быть с кошками - да еще с таким количеством разнообразных кличек - вряд ли "проканает".

Правила (утвержденного, общепринятого, с печатью "Уплочено") боюсь, тут нет, но есть ряд соображений, от которых трудно отмахнуться.

Вообще вопроса тут два. 1) Склонять ли вообще и 2) по какому образцу это делать.

Первый решается мгновенно. Спросите ребенка, он вам точно скажет, если мальчика обозвали "лошадью" его друг будет "другом Лошади" или "другом Лошадь". Думаю, достаточно. Свойство склонять все, что можно склонять, в русском языке гораздо сильнее всех заморочек с нестыковками грамматического рода объекта.

*Доводы против есть только в тенденции не склонять некоторые имена собственные: украинские фамилии на -ко, женские имена и фамилии на согласный и некоторые топонимы на -о/-е (читал Шевченко, знаком с Маргарет Тетчер, жил в Пушкино - - последнее, кстати, не общепризнанно). Но очень трудно перенести все эти вещи на случай имен-прозвищ или кличек, имеющих вполне распознаваемое и склоняемое славянское происхождение*.

С выбором образца или типа склонения (парадигмы) несколько сложнее. Известно, например, что фамилии типа Лошадь, Карамель, Мышь или Сирень" благополучно приобретаю "пол" носителя, порождают Николая Карамеля, Ивана Лошадя или Льва Мыша. То же с фамилиями типа Веретено или Шило. Но ведь это только фамилии. А если прозвища, с грамматическим согласованием, то как быть? Ну хорошо, с "Лунным Тенем" еще можно смириться (не с "Лунной Тенем" же), но как быть с остальными? Искусственно изменить тип склонения у того же "Ручейка"? Но почему только у него/неё? Нет, полагаю, правило должно быть все-таки единым.

Могу догадаться, что автор(ы) ваших текстов текстов перенесли правило о несклонении женских фамилий (см. выше) на прозвища и клички, но это крайне спорно.

Короче, предлагаю независимо от половой принадлежности **Тихого Дождя, Звонкого Ручейка, Черепашьего Хвостика, Росного** (не росистого?) **Листа, Бегущей Воды, Лунной Тени, Кривого Сука, Крика Галки, Зубчатого Пика**  - и всех скопом склонять по правилам русского языка, без учета их пола.

*Мне совсем не нравится аргументация Сержа. Во-первых, самая проблема не раскрыта: мужской или женский род при склонении ("несклонение" женских имен это лишь часть вопроса, далеко не главная), а во-вторых, ну что это за доводы "несуразица" или "[иначе] можно понять буквально"??? Да мало ли что кому-то придет в голову, что на каждый чих правила русского языка изобретать?!*

> Глаза Звонкий Ручеек (**Звонкого Ручейка**) просияли, однако она
>   решительно покачала головой.
>
> Они со **Звонким Ручейком** (это ж.р.) уселись перед заячьей тушкой и
>   принялись за еду.
>
> Отчаянные вопли Звонкий Ручеек (Звонкого Ручейка) стихали вдали.
>
> «Делайте что хотите, только сначала разбудите **Лунную Тень** (это мужское
>   имя, представленное словами ж.р.)», - донесся до него голос
>   Черепашьего Хвостика.
>
> Овраг показался Серому Крылу притихшим и опустевшим.
>
> До свидания, - промурлыкал он, потершись лбом о плечо Тихого Дождя
>
> Идем, Зубчатый Пик, - поманила его Снежная Зайчиха, незаметно кивая Тихий
>   Дождь (**Тихому Дождю**).
>
> Это будет чудесное приключение! - зеленые глаза Черепаший Хвостик 
>   (**Черепашьего Хвостика**) радостно просияли.
>
> Серое Крыло проводил взглядом **Кривого Сука** (м.р.) и Росный Лист (ж.р.
>   **Росного Листа**), уходивших на охоту.
>
> Не успел он договорить, как Серое Крыло увидел **Бегущую Воду** и Крик
>   Галки (**Крика Галки**), которые карабкались вверх по склону, неся в зубах
>   зайца.
>
> …, а Чистое Небо подталкивает Зубчатый Пик (**Зубчатого Пика**) на
>   большой, занесенный снегом камень.

Полностью за ваши варианты.

Оффтопом.

Меня больше смущает грамматическая одушевленность таких кличек. Увидел Крика Галки или Крик Галки? Тут же дело не в склонении/несклонении. Это винительный падеж одушевленного или неодушевленного объекта... Скорее всё-таки одушевленный. Если человека прозвали, к примеру, Сапогом, будет всё-таки "увидел Сапога", не "Сапог" же"?! Но не уверен для наших кличек.

**@Иванов7-й** 
Я писал. ***"Увидел Сильные Руки"***, И еще интереснее ***"Увидел Большое Сердце"***. Если и тут кто-то скажет, что склонять надо по образцу одушевленных (винительный совпадает с родительным), я буду долго смеяться.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62308/discussion-on-answer-by--------).

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется так:

Все имена склоняются в соответствии со своей ГРАММАТИКОЙ (без учета рода носителя имени, но с учетом его одушевленности), например:

1)  Глаза (кого? Р.п).) Звонкого Ручейка просияли, однако она решительно покачала головой.

2) Серое Крыло проводил взглядом  (кого? В.п.) Кривого Сука (м.р.) и Росного Листа (ж.р.) , уходивших на охоту. В данном случае выражена категория ОДУШЕВЛЕННОСТИ (В.п. по форме совпадает с Р.п.)

3) ПРИМЕР ИЗ КУПЕРА:  Отлично! — продолжал Дункан. — Пища придаст Хитрой Лисице сил, увеличит его проницательность, и он утром найдет тропинку.

Здесь мужское имя составлено из слов женского рода.

[Купер Джеймс. Последний из могикан](http://e-libra.ru/read/339847-poslednij-iz-mogikan.html)

4) Однако следует учитывать, что некоторые имена не могут выражать грамматическую одушевленность, например: я увидел Белое Облако (сущ. ср. рода не выражают грамматическую одушевленность), Голубые Глаза (мн.число как ограничение для выражения одушевленности в именах).

Answer (score -1):

Во всех ваших примерах названия правильно склонять, как одушеввленные существительные.  Поскольку имена животных относятся к одушевеленным именам существительным.

Ср.: **Глаза Звонкий Ручеек просияли, однако она решительно покачала головой.** В этом примире несклоняемый варант указывает на то, что просияли глаза, а не кот(кошка). А Звонкий ручьек - это или названия глаз или метафора: аетора сравнивает глаза со звонким ручейком.

**Отчаянные вопли Звонкий Ручеек (Звонкого Ручейка) стихали вдали**. В этом примере то же самое: или навания вопля или метафора. Это создает комичный эффект.

Идем, Зубчатый Пик, - поманила его Снежная Зайчиха, незаметно кивая Тихий Дождь. Ошибка в упавлении. Нужен родительный падеж. В данным случае глагол "кивать" в значении  требует родительного падежа.  **Кивать: на кого (что). Указывать на кого-что-н. движением головы.**

Серое Крыло проводил взглядом Кривого Сука (м.р.) и Росный Лист (ж.р. Росного Листа), уходивших на охоту. Ошибка в управлении при однородных однородных членах: 
 проводил взглядом(кого) Кривого Сука (м.р.) и(кого ) -  Росный Лист**. Это род.пад.**. Иначе получается, что Росный лист**(**винительный падеж**)неодушевленное существительное.

Не успел он договорить, как Серое Крыло увидел(кого) Бегущую Воду и(кого) Крик Галки, которые карабкались вверх по склону, неся в зубах зайца.

Опять несуразица: **крик галки увидеть невозможно!**

а Чистое Небо подталкивает Зубчатый Пик на большой, занесенный снегом камень.

В этом примере **Зубчатый пик** можно понять дословно, а не как чье-то имя.

Comment: Простите, **Тихий Дождь** вы склонять предлагаете или нет? Если да, то как? Как Мышь или как Учитель?

Comment: Я же написал: надо склонять. Ну не напишите же вы: увидел тихую дождя. Увидел Тихого дождя. Если были бы одиночные прилагательные, склонять можно было бы  в женском роде. А так надо соглосовать по правилам русского языка.

Comment: @ Мимоходов, где я предлагал не склонять Росный лист или Лунную Тень?

Comment: Мимоходов, в своем ответе  в примерах я не склонял названия, чтобы показать, что несклоняемый вариант меняет значение. Я же объяснял. .

Comment: Автор приводил склоняемый и несклонярмый варианты. Я написал: надо склонять.

Comment: Правильно, в тексте не написал. Но рядом с несклоняемым вариантом я я пишу,что он неверный.

Comment: По поводу одушевленности. Вы же сами знаете, что винительный падеж одушевленных существительных совпадает с родительным. А поскольку имена животных одушевленные, значит нужен родительный падеж.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62279/discussion-between--and-).

Comment: Ответа на свой исходный вопрос не получил.

Comment: Как то у Вас слегка путано написано. Если вкратце - Вы за мой вариант, или за вариант из издания?