# О склонении и одушевленности

Tags: грамматика, одушевленность, склоняемость

Был вопрос о кошачьих именах

[Склонение женских имён, составленных из слов мужского рода](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/433139)

На него был получен безапелляционный ответ.

> Во всех ваших примерах названия правильно склонять, как одушеввленные
>   существительные. Поскольку имена животных относятся к одушевеленным
>   именам существительным.

Причем это не оговорка и не случайная небрежность, автор и в комментариях сознательно выводит "склонение" из "одушевленности".

Оставим на совести автора вопроса его формулировку, дальше становится понятно, речь идет о склонении таких имен как **Тихий Дождь, Звонкий Ручеек, Черепаший Хвостик, Росный Лист**... - и это все **имена кошек, не котов**. То есть речь идет о склонении/несклонении **женских** имен, не имеющих формального признака женского рода. Это все обсуждается в той теме.

Но вот в связи с процитированным **ответом** возникает масса дополнительных вопросов.

1. Являются ли такие имена грамматически одушевленными? В современном русском, напомню, категория одушевленности проявляется лишь в форме винительного падежа слов мужского рода и винительного же падежа множественного числа (всех родов).
2. Если да, то как далеко распространяется эта одушевленность? Имена типа *Доброе Сердце* или *Сильные Руки* - грамматически одушевлены? "Я увидел *Доброго Сердца*"?! С этим вообще интересно, в русском нет парадигмы для одушевленных имен среднего рода, можно ли вообще говорить об одушевленности/неодушевленности таких слов?!
3. Какие вообще существительные можно называть несклоняемыми (ведь если следовать логике автора ответа, получается, что неодушевленные существительные вообще "несклоняемые"). Другими словами, насколько правомерно использовать речевой оборот типа "(не)склоняемые в родительном падеже"?!
   Если всё это не так, то есть ли вообще хоть малейшие причины связывать одушевленность и склоняемость (противопоставляя неодушевленности и несклоняемости)?!
4. Ну и всё прочее, вытекающее из сопоставления склоняемости и одушевленности. Например, имя манекена (в космонавтике принято "Иван Иваныч") - одушевлено? Если да, то дело явно не в кличках (домашних животных), а в сути родового понятия. Или вот такой вопрос сразу возникает, а о какой одушевленности идет речь? Реальной или чисто грамматической?  Имя трупа, получается, неодушевлено? А покойника - одушевлено?!
5. И вишенка на торте. Женские имена типа Ирен или Николь - одушевлены? Но несклоняемы? Тогда получается, применительно к женскому роду вообще понятие "одушевленности" не актуально?! Или все-таки "склоняемость" - это совсем не то, о чем тут подумали?!

//-----

Список вопрос пополняется.

Кто-нибудь может перевести это на русский?! Что здесь не понравилось автору?!

> Вы пишете: "Являются ли такие имена грамматически одушевленными?" Ну
>   ведь вы сами сами в прошлом ответе написали: "...Должны склоняться в
>   соответствии с грамматическим родом этих имен". В тексте вы употребили
>   род,пад. А здесь это показатель одушевленности.

Я могу сказать:
*i). "Являются ли такие имена грамматически одушевленными?" - Да задал такой вопрос.

ii) "...Должны склоняться в соответствии с грамматическим родом этих имен" - да, вопрос в том какой это род.

iii)  "В тексте вы употребили род,пад. А здесь это показатель одушевленности" - Вот это не поддается моему пониманию. Я не употреблял "род,пад." И вообще, проявление категории одушевленности в русском фиксируется только в **винительном падеже**. Если (для оговоренных случаев) он совпадает с родительным, то имя одушевлено. Ничего более по этому поводу я не знаю.*

> Если вы говорите, что надо склонять по грамматическому роду таких
>   имен, тогда получается, что имена эти грамматически одушевеленные

*iv) Это тоже - помощь зала. Кто-нибудь может пояснить, что здесь имеется в виду? У меня есть укрепляется подозрение, что автор просто не понимает категории грамматического рода, которой нет в его родном языке*.

И до кучи.

> Если авторы решили назвать женскими именами котов, а мужскими кошек,
>   пусть! Это их дело. Мой ответ: на грамматике это не должно отражаться*

*v) А это как понимать? В чем автор видит грамматику, на которой (якобы) не должно отражаться?*

Comment: Вы сами себе противоречите. Если авторы решили назвать кошку мужским именем( хотя это может и противоречить здравому смыслу), но на граматику это никаким образом не должно отражаться. Раз имена представлена в мужском роде, то и должны склоняться в соответствии с грамматическим родом этих имен.

Comment: @Серж  Я пока вопросы задаю, тезисов у меня нет. Противоречит сам себе не могу в принципе. Впрочем, можете указать на два моих тезиса, которые показались вам такими "противоречивыми". Иначе все это - пустой звук.

Comment: Вы  пишете: "Являются ли такие имена грамматически одушевленными?" Ну ведь вы сами сами в прошлом ответе написали: "...Должны склоняться в соответствии с грамматическим родом этих имен".

Comment: В тексте вы употребили род,пад. А здесь это показатель одушевленности.

Comment: @Серж, ответь, пожалуйста, сначала на вопрос по поводу противоречия. В чем конкретно у меня противоречивость. Остальное - потом. Что я пишу, я и без вас знаю.

Comment: Если вы говорите, что надо склонять по грамматическому роду таких имен, тогда получается, что имена эти грамматически одушевеленные. Но вы-то несогласны.

Comment: И так, и так говорите.

Comment: *Но вы-то несогласны* - я ни о чем таком даже не говорил. Но если вам интересно, то я даже всерьез не рассматриваю подобный тезис.  Одушевленность в русском никак не связана с грамматическим родом. Единственное, что имеет место - слова среднего рода обычно неодушевлены (слово "дитя". выносим за скобки). Но это никак не связано с темой разговора.

Comment: Категория одушевленности проявляется в винительнм падеже у слов муж.род. В этом случае вин.п. совпадает с род.пад. Серое Крыло проводил взглядом Кривого Сука (м.р.) Здесь вин.пад. совпает с род. верно?

Comment: Если бы имя Кривой Сук было бы неодушевеленным, тогда здесь был бы вин.неод. ...проводил  взглядом Кривой Сук

Comment: Никто и не говорил, что кат.одушевл. связана с грамматическим родом.

Comment: Если авторы решили назвать женскими именами котов, а мужскими кошек, пусть! Это их дело. Мой ответ: на грамматике это не должно отражаться.

Comment: *Никто и не говорил, что кат.одушевл. связана с грамматическим родом* - Да? А двумя строчками выше: *[если] надо склонять по грамматическому роду таких имен, тогда получается, что имена эти грамматически одушевеленные*.  @Серж, могу только предложить сформулировать ваши ответы в собственно ответе. Следить за полетом вашей мысли в комментариях уже просто нет сил. *Если авторы решили назвать женскими именами котов, а мужскими кошек, пусть! Это их дело. Мой ответ: на грамматике это не должно отражаться* - тезис сам по себе неочевилный, но в чем состоит грамматика, на котой-де не должно?!

Comment: Вы все запутали! Резумирую: мужские имена склонять как мужские, женские как женские. Независимо от пола! Теперь понятно?

Comment: *мужские имена склонять как мужские, женские как женские. Независимо от пола! Теперь понятно* - теперь совсем непонятно. Да и не спрашиваю я вас давно об этом. Ответьте, пожалуйста, на те вопросы, которые поставлены.

Answer (score 1):

Что я об этом думаю.

1) Склоняемость/несклоняемость и одушевленность/неодушевленность - разные грамматические категории, они  могут иметь только косвенную связь.

2) Грамматическую одушевленность выражают  только сущ. м.р. 2 скл. ед. числа  и все сущ. во мн.числе. Выражается одушевленность тем, что для одуш. сущ. В. падеж совпадает с Р. падежом, а для неодуш. сущ. В. падеж совпадает с И. падежом (может быть, это понимается как  несклоняемость?!).

3) Реальная и грамматическая одушевленность могут не совпадать, например: девочки любят кукол (одуш.), увидеть покойника (одуш.) во сне.

4) Несклоняемые существительные не могут выражать грамматическую одушевленность, так как имеют только одну форму (но при наличии прилагательного одушевленность можно выразить, например: я увидел большого какаду).

5) Об именах. Я увидел Хитрую Лисицу, Соколиного Глаза,  Доброе Сердце, Сильные Руки. Очевидно, имена одушевленных существ (людей или кошек) не всегда имеют грамматическую одушевленность. Это может иметь разные причины, например: сердце - сущ. ср. рода, не выражает грам. одушевленность; сущ. в форме мн.  числа сложно представить как один одушевленный предмет и т.д.